# Using "be_routable" matcher in a shared example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

It looks like using the "be_routable" matcher in a shared example, not residing in the controller or routing subdirectory is not possible?

If I try

```
expect(get :edit, id: 1).not_to be_routable
```

I get an error

```
Failure/Error: expect(get :edit, id: 1).not_to be_routable
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:id=>"1", :controller=>"leads", :action=>"edit"}
```

I include this shared example from within the controller directory, so I would guess this should be fine

I already tried by adding "type: :controller" to the describe, but seems not to solve the problem

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Peter's first answer, I finally started checking the syntax, letter by letter, and the reason it is not working is... a colon. If you change

```
expect(get :edit, id: 1).not_to be_routable
```

to

```
expect(get: :edit, id: 1).not_to be_routable
```

it works like a charm!

Comment: Sorry about that. The documentation I pointed you to was for 2.4 and has since changed. I've never really noticed this way of using `expect` before, where the first argument is missing (normally the value that gets compared) and the matcher is just using the optional parameters that go with it. Sorry for the confusion, but I sure learned something.

Comment: I actually arrived at this same conclusion and was posting a revised answer when I saw yours. +1 for correctness as well as pain and suffering.